# Por que o CSS funciona com elementos "falsos" do HTML?

Tags: html, css

Vi alguns exemplos como esse na internet, mostrando que elementos do html com nomes personalizados funcionam em relação a aplicação de estilos css.

```css
elementofake {
  color:red;
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<elementofake>Olá mundo.</elementofake>
```

Gostaria de saber porque isso funciona e se esta prática é comum no desenvolvimento web.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Creio que seja tudo devido a como ocorreu a evolução do HTML, XHTML e CSS.

O CSS pode customizar qualquer tipo de elemento que seja valido dentro do HTML e até mesmo alguns elementos XML. Note que no passado remoto houve o XHTML (algo que é praticamente embutido dentro do HTML5), ou seja não são elementos falsos, mas sim customizados.

> um exemplo que podemos customizar são elementos do SVG (um xml para imagens vetoriais)

Ou seja, o HTML é como se fosse um XML, no entanto bem mais "permissivo", os seletores então provavelmente devem ser livres para manipular, houve até mesmo variações do XHTML, como:

- XHTML 1
- XHTML Mobile Profile
- XHTML 2.0
- XHTML5

Ou seja, o CSS não foi só criado para atender o *HTML padrão*, mas qualquer formato semelhante de *[linguagens de marcação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_marca%C3%A7%C3%A3o)*. O resto vai depender do renderizador que vai processar o CSS.

Claro que hoje o XHTML tecnicamente não existe (apesar do HTML5 praticamente suportar tudo o que ele fazia), mas a herança do CSS ser "livre" para qualquer tipo de tag ficou.

Note também que a evolução do HTML não segue sincronizada com o CSS, cada um evolui ao seu tempo, ou seja, se o CSS só permitisse "tags validas" não teríamos como customizar tags novas que fossem "implementadas" no HTML.

Comment: Acredito que também seja válido citar os [*web components*](https://www.webcomponents.org/), que funcionam sobre elementos customizados.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ótimo, vou ler e depois ler este https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/ e então atualizo ;)

Answer (score 10):

A maioria dos browsers são feitos de maneira a aceitar compatibilidade com possíveis futuros elementos de HTML. Portanto, elementos não reconhecidos são adicionados mas não terão nenhum tipo de renderização padrão associadas a ele.

Porém, não é uma prática comum, pois

- Eles não são permitidos pela especificação do HTML
- Pode haver conflito com elementos futuros de mesmo nome
- Provavelmente há um elemento existente que faça a mesma tarefa igualmente bem ou até mesmo melhor.

Baseei minha resposta na resposta dada a uma pergunta semelhante, que pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353613/why-does-css-work-with-fake-elements)

Comment: Acho que eles são sim permitidos pela especificação, [aqui](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#autonomous-custom-element)  e [aqui](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#custom-elements) e também nesta [do Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements) falam sobre isso. A única recomendação ("obrigação") é que eles devem conter `-`, por exemplo `<elemento-personalizado></elemento-personalizado>`, também não pode fechar automaticamente, isto `<elemento-personalizado />` é inválido.

Answer (score 6):

Elementos `fakes` são tratados como divs pelos navegadores modernos. É por isso que eles funcionam. Isso faz parte do próprio padrão HTML5 que introduz uma estrutura modular à qual novos elementos podem ser adicionados.

#### Os elementos e atributos personalizados são válidos em HTML, desde que:

- Os nomes dos elementos são minúsculos e começam com x-
- Os nomes dos
  atributos são minúsculos e começam com data-

Por exemplo, `<x-foo data-bar="gaz"/>` ou `<br data-bar="gaz"/>`.

[Mais informações.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements)

Comment: Acho que se confundiu amigo, não são tratados como DIVs, o padrão de elementos *"customizados"* é `inline`, DIVs são `block`.